# AutoCorrelation Matrix vs Covariance Matrix for the MUSIC Algorithm

Tags: autocorrelation

What is the difference between an autocovariance matrix and autocorrelation matrix?

Comment: After reading [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation_matrix), what exactly is it that you don't understand?

Comment: well the reason I was asking, was I wanted to identify which one should be used in the MUSIC Algorithm for estimating frequency spectrum. I have seen articles where the correlation matrix or the covariance matrix is decomposed and wanted to identify what the difference was between the two.

Answer (score 5):

That really depends on who is asking and precisely what definitions you want to use.

In signal processing, the [**autocovariance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocovariance) is usually a non-normalized, mean-corrected quantity derived from a stochastic process (sequence of random variables):
$$
C_{xx}(n,m) = E\left[ (x[n] - \mu_x) (x[m] - \mu_x) \right]
$$

Similarly, the [**autocorrelation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation_matrix) is usually a non-normalized, non-mean-corrected quantity derived from a stochastic process (sequence of random variables):
$$
R_{xx}(n,m) = E\left[ x[n] x[m] \right]
$$

Some fields, however, require a **correlation** (auto or otherwise) to be normalized to lie between $-1$ and $+1$. Some in signal processing also prefer this definition.